# Ejabberd : make && make install does not update ejabberd.yml file?

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I want to add a hook to ejabbered code. Steps followed:

- added mod_filter.erl to src folder(mod_filter catches filter_packet event and returns modified packet)
- added mod_filter in ejjbaerd.yml under modules section.
- ran ./configure, make , make install

Ejabberd server runs successfully , with mod_filter.beam file in /ebin folder but the ejabberd.yml file located at /etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.yml does not get updated as per my second step.

I can manually update it and restart server but that does not seem to be the correct way. I think i might be missing a deployment step here, please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Change configuration file (ejabberd.yml) according to your need and reload configuration file like that- *ejabberd_ctl reload_config* or *ejabberd_config:reload_file().* or *ejabberd_config:load_file("/etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.yml").* you do not need to restart server.

```
https://www.ejabberd.im/tricks
https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/api/
```